# Select elements whose title begins with a string AND have a specific class

Tags: jquery, class, selector, title

I want to select items that have a specific class **and** their titles start with a specific string. The below isn't working for me — elements that match only one of the conditions are being selected. How can I specify that both must be matched?

```js
var $elementsIWant = $('.hoverClass, div[title^="Click here"]');

$elementsIWant.mouseenter(function () {
  $('.box').css({
    'background-color': 'red'
  })
});

$elementsIWant.mouseleave(function () {
  $('.box').css({
    'background-color': 'white'
  })
});
```

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div title="Click here for more information" class="hoverClass">
  Hovering over this element should change the box red
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div title="Fake title" class="hoverClass">
  Hovering over this element shouldn't change the box
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div title="Click here for more information" class="fakeClass">
  Hovering over this element shouldn't change the box
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Just like in CSS, an *AND* statement involves selectors without spaces or commas.  Commas are *OR* statements in CSS.  Spaces are descendent statements

Comment: try `div.hoverClass[title^="Click here"]`

Comment: Side note, you can achieve this in CSS alone, assuming you don't need to support IE

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan wouldn't `div.hoverClass[title^="Click here"] ~ .box {}`  work in IE?  The general sibling combinator selector seems to have IE coverage from what I'm seeing on MDN. EDIT: Well, IE 7+

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan but the CSS was just to show the issue on this page, the actual code that will be triggered by the event handler requires JQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You're using two different selectors. Either of those matched, will be selected. You need to combine those instead:

```
var $elementsIWant = $('div.hoverClass[title^="Click here"]');
```

Refer to the following demo:

```js
var $elementsIWant = $('div.hoverClass[title^="Click here"]');

$elementsIWant.mouseenter(function () {
  $('.box').css({
    'background-color': 'red'
  })
});

$elementsIWant.mouseleave(function () {
  $('.box').css({
    'background-color': 'white'
  })
});
```

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div title="Click here for more information" class="hoverClass">
  Hovering over this element should change the box red
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div title="Fake title" class="hoverClass">
  Hovering over this element shouldn't change the box
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div title="Click here for more information" class="fakeClass">
  Hovering over this element shouldn't change the box
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="box">
</div>
```